# Deserialization requires a parameterless constructor

Tags: uno-platform, webassembly

I’ve an issue when using a .Net Standard 2.0 Nuget (same issue linking directly project) in WASM (#uno-platform):

Deserialization requires à parameterless constructor (Microsoft & Newtonsoft deserializator).

Obviously, the involved classes have parameterless constructors and the Nuget is working fine with UWP, WPF and Xamarin projects:

```
public class MCEFile
{
  public List<Form> Forms { get; set; }
  public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

  [JsonConstructor]
  public MCEFile()
  {
     Forms = new List<Form>();
     Items = new List<Item>();
  }
}

public class Item
{
  public long ID { get; set; }

  ...

  // - - -  - - - 

  [JsonConstructor]
  public Item()
  {
     // dummy for WASM
  }
```

}

Any clue? Is there a solution or workaround? Or an issue I can follow?

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally caused by a linker configuration issue.

If the class you are deserializing is located in an assembly or project that is not directly in the WebAssembly head project, you'll need to include the assembly name in the `LinkerConfig.xml` file.

For example:

```xml
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="MyProject.Wasm" />

  <assembly fullname="MyOtherLibrary" />

  <assembly fullname="System.Core">
    <!-- This is required by Json.NET and any expression.Compile caller -->
    <type fullname="System.Linq.Expressions*" />
  </assembly>
</linker>
```